# How do I use BigDecimal to increase the accuracy of this method?

Tags: java, precision, bigdecimal

I have written the following simple function that calculates the arctan of the inverse of an integer. I was wondering how to use BigDecimal instead of double to increase the accuracy of the results. I was also thinking of using a BigInteger to store the growing multiples of xSquare that the "term" value is divided by.

I have limited experience with the syntax for how to perform calculations on BigDecimals. How would I revise this function to use them?

/* Thanks to https://www.cygnus-software.com/misc/pidigits.htm for explaining the general calculation method
credited to John Machin.
*/

```
public static double atanInvInt(int x) {
        // Returns the arc tangent of an inverse integer
        /* Terminates once the remaining amount reaches zero or the denominator reaches 2101.
        If the former happens, the accuracy should be determined by the number format used, such as double.
        If the latter happens, the result should be off by at most one from the correct nearest value
                    in the seventh decimal place, if allowed by the accuracy of the number format used.
                    This likely only happens if the integer is 1.
        */
        int xSquare = x*x;
        double result = ((double)1)/x;
        double term = ((double)1)/x;
        int divisor = 1;
        double midResult;
        while ((term > 0)) {
            term = term / xSquare;
            divisor += 2;
            midResult = result - term/divisor;
            term = term /xSquare;
            divisor += 2;
            result = midResult + term/divisor;
            if (divisor >= 2101) {
                return ((result + midResult) / 2);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: You have attracted an answer in this case, but in future why don't you consult a tutorial? It seems strange to ask for someone to write one for you when there are thousands out there, not to mention the mountains of official and unofficial documentation.

Comment: Unfortunately, to fully express my answer as to why it was helpful to see code "in action" that does the specific things I want to do, it takes much more than the 600 characters allotted. I do not know whether it would be more appropriate to post it as a series of ten comments or to post it as an answer, but I can delineate a number of reasons why seeing this sample code is different from reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The BigDecimal provides very intuitive wrapper methods to provide all the different operations. you can have something like this to have an arbitrary precision of, for example, 99:

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(atanInvInt(5, 99));
        // 0.197395559849880758370049765194790293447585103787852101517688940241033969978243785732697828037288045
    }

    public static BigDecimal atanInvInt(int x, int scale) {
        BigDecimal one = new BigDecimal("1");
        BigDecimal two = new BigDecimal("2");
        BigDecimal xVal = new BigDecimal(x);
        BigDecimal xSquare = xVal.multiply(xVal);
        BigDecimal divisor = new BigDecimal(1);

        BigDecimal result = one.divide(xVal, scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        BigDecimal term = one.divide(xVal, scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
        BigDecimal midResult;

        while (term.compareTo(new BigDecimal(0)) > 0) {
            term = term.divide(xSquare, scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
            divisor = divisor.add(two);
            midResult = result.subtract(term.divide(divisor, scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR));
            term = term.divide(xSquare, scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
            divisor = divisor.add(two);
            result = midResult.add(term.divide(divisor, scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR));

            if (divisor.compareTo(new BigDecimal(2101)) >= 0) {
                return result.add(midResult).divide(two, scale, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who wanted to know why it was beneficial to pose this question to begin with: That is a fair question. I have written a rather long answer to it. I believe that writing this answer helped me to articulate to myself things about the BigDecimal class that are more intuitive now that I have Armando Carballo’s answer than they were before, so writing it was hopefully educational. I can only hope that reading it will be as well, though likely in a different way if at all.

The official documentation lists methods, but it doesn’t explain how they are used in the same way that Armando Carballo’s code demonstrates. For example, while the way the BigDecimal.divide method works is pretty intuitive, there is nothing in the official documentation that says “to take the mean of two numbers, not only should you have BigDecimals for those two numbers, but you should also create a BigDecimal equal to 2 and apply the BigDecimal.divide method to the result of a BigDecimal.add operation with the 2 BigDecimal as the input for the divisor.” This is something that is simple enough to be perfectly intuitive once you see it, but if you’ve never used object-oriented methods for the specific purpose of performing arithmetic before, it may be less intuitive the first time you are trying to figure out how to take the mean.

As another example, consider the idea that to figure out whether a number is greater than or equal to another number, instead of using a Boolean operator on the two numbers, you use a compareTo method that can give three possible outputs on one number with the other number as an input, then apply a Boolean operator to the output of that method. This makes perfect sense once you see it in action and have a quick sense of how the compareTo method works, but may be less obvious when you’re staring at a quick description of the compareTo method in the official documentation, even if the description is clear and you are able to figure out what the compareTo method will output with a given BigDecimal value calling the method and a given BigDecimal input as the comparison value. For anyone who has used compareTo methods with other classes besides BigDecimal extensively, this is probably obvious even if they’re new to the specific class, but if you haven’t used Booleans on the result of ANY compareTo method recently, it’s faster to see it.

When working with ints, you might very well write code a bit like this:

```
int x = 5;
x = x + 2;
System.out.println(x) // should be 7
```

Here, the “2” value was never declared to be an int. The result of the addition was the same as if we had declared y=2 and said that x = x+y instead of x = x+2, but with the above lines of code no named variable, or Integer object if we used those instead of primitive ints, was created for the “2”. With BigDecimal, on the other hand, since the BigDecimal.add method requires BigDecimals as inputs, it would be mandatory to create a BigDecimal equal to 2 in order to add 2. I don’t see anything in the official documentation that says “use this as a more accurate substitute for doubles, or for longs if you want something more versatile than BigInteger, but in addition to using it as a substitute for declared variables, also create BigDecimal objects equal to small integers that by themselves wouldn’t call for the use of the BigDecimal class so that you can use them in operations. Both your variables and the small values you are adding to them need to be BigDecimals if you want to use BigDecimals.”

Finally, let me explain something that has the potential to make the BigDecimal class more intimidating than it needs to be. Anyone who has ever worked with primitive arrays and tried to predict in advance at the time the array is created exactly how large it needs to be, or is familiar with how lower-level languages involve certain situations in which a programmer needs to know exactly how many bytes something takes up, may feel the need for caution when dealing with something that seems to demand a specified level of precision upfront. The documentation says this: “If no rounding mode is specified and the exact result cannot be represented, an exception is thrown; otherwise, calculations can be carried out to a chosen precision and rounding mode by supplying an appropriate MathContext object to the operation.” A newbie reading that sentence for the first time may be thinking that they are going to have to think extensively about rounding when writing their code for the first time or else face exceptions as soon as a value cannot be represented exactly, or that they are going to have to read the documentation on the MathContext object as well before using BigDecimal, which in turn might lead to reading IEEE standards that help grant an understanding of floating point numbers but are far removed from what the person actually wanted to code. Seeing that some of the constructors for BigDecimal take arrays as inputs and that others take a MathContext as an input, along with noticing that one of the constructors for the related BigInteger class takes a byte array as the input, may strengthen the feeling that using this object class requires a very fine understanding of the exact number of digits that will be used for the specific calculations the class is used for and that understanding MathContext is more or less essential to even the most basic use of the class. While I’m sure understanding MathContext is helpful, baby’s first BigDecimal project can actually work perfectly well without the need to learn this added functionality at the same time as the first use of the BigDecimal. Reading up on the scale parameter might also lead to the belief by a coder looking up info on the class for the first time that it is necessary to predict the order of magnitude of the answer in advance in order to use the class at all.

Armando Caballo’s commendable answer shows that these concerns of a hypothetical newbie are overblown, as while rounding mode does need to be specified fairly often and a consistent scale is often called as a parameter when using the divide method, the scale parameter is actually a fairly arbitrary specification of the desired accuracy in terms of number of decimal places and not something that requires pinpoint predictions about exactly what numbers the class will handle (unless the ultimate purpose for which the BigDecimal is being used requires a finely controlled level of accuracy, in which case it is fairly easy to specify). An “infinite” series of added and subtracted terms to compute an arc tangent was processed without ever declaring a MathContext object.